# Clustering documents Lucene

Tags: lucene, cluster-analysis

I would like to implement an algorithm for clustering and implement it in Lucene. For that, I need the tf-idf term vector that represents the document, so I could represent the centroids the same way documents are represented, find the similarity between documents and clusters, and update the centroids, by calculating its new feature values. But how can I do that on top of Lucene?

Can I even get tf-idf?

I know that term frequency in each document is saved, but does that mean that I would need to calculate idf 'manually' for each term? And how to make vectors then to use them for clustering.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store term vectors for the field. Then for particular document you can get the term vector:

```
Terms termFreqVector = indexReader.getTermVector(doc, field);
TermsEnum te = termFreqVector.iterator(null);
```

and then iterating over the enum for each term you can use methods:

```
long df = te.docFreq(); // df of the term
long tf = te.totalTermFreq(); // tf of the term
```

to obtain idf you can divide the df by indexReader.numDocs() and apply Math.log

Of course you also can use Mahout tools for vectorizing lucene documents: http://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html

Comment: But if I want to implement clustering algorithm, that is, to take values of term vectors and calculate distance between them, I need to create the vectors myself, there is no other way?

Comment: If you want to represent each document of lucene index as a vector and then to apply some clustering algorithms to these vectors then you can implement such "document to vector" transformation by using method I described above. There is no standard method in lucene for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's the thing I needed to hear, because I was not sure if there is already something that I am missing and I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Note that lucene uses a *variation* of TF-IDF as you would find it in textbooks.

You can see details here:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

In particular, *only terms used in the query are accessed*. This is essentially for the performance of Lucene: *read as little data from the index as necessary*.

If you want access to the exact similarity value, you may want to use a [`Collector`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html) or some of the other expert-level APIs.